Send Whatsapp Typing Indicator to Twilio Conversation using Python
I could not find an example online of how to send Whatsapp indicator to twilio conversation using Python.
Does somebody have an example of how to implement this, please?
from twilio.rest import Client      
api_key = "XXXXX"api_secret = "YYYYY"     
account_sid = "RRRRRR"     
conversation_sid = 'AAAAA'
participant_sid = 'BBBBB'      
client = Client(api_key, api_secret, account_sid)     
conversation = client.conversations.v1.conversations(conversation_sid).fetch() 
conversation.typing()

I tried was a lots of variations of this, but none of them worked.]

I'm afraid this feature is, as of now, not available on the WhatsApp API. Therefore, Twilio can't offer such a feature either.
You are probably referring to this doc but that one covers Twilio Conversations in general and not all features of the Conversations API can map to the WhatsApp channel
